# Android Button Background

Tags: android, xml

В XML файле ( их там 2 ) прописал код для моих кнопок ( pressed или не pressed ). Запускаю эмулятор, но при нажатии на кнопку не меняется ее картинка.
Что я делаю неправильно? 
Чистил проект, перезапускал Android Studio.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще, в настройках(properties) кнопки показывает, что все нормально. То есть если кнопка не нажата, картинка одна, если нажата, то другая.

Comment: Не надо скрин.Выложите код текстом

Answer (score 1):

### btn_click.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false"android:drawable="@drawable/btn_unpressed"/>
</selector>
```

И не забудьте, про саму кнопку:

```
...
android:background="@drawable/btn_click"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя в обеих случаях state_pressed="TRUE";

Попробуй сделать так...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/clickedbutton" /> <!-- pressed -->

<item android:state_hovered="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/defaultbutton" /> <!-- hovered -->

<item android:drawable="@drawable/defaultbutton" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: А зачем hovered и default? Там же одни и те же картинки